# Trim the middle of a file name

Tags: terminal, trim

I have a lot of files in a directory that have `[!]` in the file name. Is there a way to trim that out with a command in the terminal? Here's an example filename. `file001[!].ext`

Comment: you want to remove a specific character in file name?

Comment: character's'. Specifically, the one's I mentioned. `[!]`

Answer (score 3):

Yosemite features a graphical way to do this. Select all the files you want to rename, Control-click on them, select "Rename x Items...", and you'll get what is basically a find-and-replace window for file names.

[image]

---

In your case, select "Replace text" and substitute "[!]" with the empty string.

[image]

Comment: Got to say did not know about. Nice one

Comment: Another thank you for this great tip. Often this is all you need.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use the '[sed](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/sed.1.html)' command.  You can run a for each loop over all the files and parse out the "[!]".

```
sed 's/\[!]//'
```

for loop version:

```
for f in /path/to/files/*; do
rename=`echo "$f" | sed 's/\[!]//'`
mv "$f" "$rename"
done
```

Otherwise I would suggest installing "[rename](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/)" from homebrew if you have that installed.  I also have a Automator right click service that does batch rename's if you would like a graphical way.

Comment: I'd add an `if` statement before `mv` to preserve timestamps for files that do not need to be renamed.